# How to 3D view button and and textFields in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

hi I want create app like complete 3D module in jetpack compose in android can anybody please suggest me any thing do good library or modules for this, thanks in advance.
[image: check sample image]

Comment: You can do it with `Modifier.shadow(some dp value, CircleShape).background()`

Comment: is this workout  for all  element ?

Comment: It should, it's a `Modifier` you assign to Composables such as background, border or padding